# MobX reactive state on react native

Tags: react-native, mobx-react

i'm working on developing a function for achievements page where the levels, image and target will change depends on the current score. But the code doesn't seems to works when the page mounted.

im using MobX for state management store, and my code is below:

```
import { observable, computed, action } from 'mobx';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export default class Trophy {

    @observable ScoreBoard = [
     {
        scoreID: 0,
        scoreTitle: 'Trophy 0',
        scoreIcons: require('../../assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
        scoreCurrent: 1010,
        scoreTarget: 1000,
        scoreLevel: 1
    }, {
        scoreID: 1,
        scoreTitle: 'Trophy 1',
        scoreIcons: require('../../assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
        scoreCurrent: 0,
        scoreTarget: 1000,
        scoreLevel: 1
    }, {
        scoreID: 2,
        scoreTitle: 'Trophy 2',
        scoreIcons: require('../../assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
        scoreCurrent: 0,
        scoreTarget: 1000,
        scoreLevel: 1
    }, {
        scoreID: 3,
        scoreTitle: 'Trophy 3',
        scoreIcons: require('../../assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
        scoreCurrent: 0,
        scoreTarget: 1000,
        scoreLevel: 1
    }, {
        scoreID: 4,
        scoreTitle: 'Trophy 4',
        scoreIcons: require('../../assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
        scoreCurrent: 0,
        scoreTarget: 1000,
        scoreLevel: 1
    }, {
        scoreID: 5,
        scoreTitle: 'Trophy 5',
        scoreIcons: require('../../assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
        scoreCurrent: 0,
        scoreTarget: 1000,
        scoreLevel: 1
    }
]

@computed get updateScore() {
    // Dive into each score block
    this.ScoreBoard.forEach((score) => {
        if(score.scoreID === 1) {
            if(score.scoreCurrent >= 0 && score.scoreCurrent < 1000) {
                return console.log('level 1');
            }else if(score.scoreCurrent >= 1001 && score.scoreCurrent < 2000){
                return console.log('level 2');
                this.score.scoreLevel = 2;
                this.score.scoreTarget = 2000;
            }else if(score.scoreCurrent >= 2001 && score.scoreCurrent < 3000) {
                return console.log('level 3');
            }else if(score.scoreCurrent <= 3001) {
                return console.log('level 4');
            }
        }else if(score.scoreID === 2) {
            return console.log(score.scoreTitle);
        }else if(score.scoreID === 3) {
            return console.log(score.scoreTitle);
        }else if(score.scoreID === 4) {
                return console.log(score.scoreTitle);
           }else if(score.scoreID === 5) {
                return console.log(score.scoreTitle);
            }else {
                return console.log(score.scoreTitle);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

my idea is every time this store runs, the logic get the current score from each score block, then it will help to set the correct image, title & target score base on current score. And all logic will be process first in this store before being inject into the view page with correct data, for cleaner code structure.

but the problem now is, the logic not even giving the console.log output.

May i know how do i fix this to make it runs? why it doesn't run like i want it?

thanks! Terima kasih!